# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 87 bytes)

Tags: php, cakephp

When I login to my web application it shows an error like:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 87 bytes) in /gt/2.ps.fo/home/hft/domains/console.fo.spalgo.com/public_html/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_mysql.php on line 775

Is there any solution to solve this problem? Why do I get this error?

Comment: It means your code is doing something that uses up all available memory. Fix it so it uses less memory and/or does less.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That sounds like you've allocated [more memory than PHP will allow](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit). Edit the `memory_limit` setting in your site `php.ini` configuration as described on the linked page.

Another possibility (less likely) is that you've hit the `setrlimit(2)` resource limits for your user or group. Check `/etc/security/limits.conf` for limits that might be set for your web server, along with whatever initialization scripts start your server environment and PHP interpreter environment.

Comment: Though both statements are probable, it is more likely related to the memory limit, however, just increasing it, thought it will solve it, it may not be the right solution as you have to check why is a single script allocating that much memory. To complement your answer, I added another one.

Answer (score 3):

The first example I found by searching SO for "PHP out of memory" is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847396/php-application-running-out-of-memory)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `echo` instead of storing what you are printing to a variable first.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the file that threw the fatal exception (`dbo_mysql.php`) I presume that your call is retrieving data from the DataBase.

Also, looking at the memory limit, it shows 134217728 bytes, which is 128MB, so I think that whatever your API call is doing, is trying to fetch a lot of data which total surpasses the limit allocated per script.
For example, if the last script in the API call stack were to use `20MB` for its needs and then tires to fetch data from the DB worth `115MB`, your script would be trying to allocate `135MB` which is already `7MB` more than the limit and thus causing the `Fatal Exception`.

So, I see a few things to check/do:

1. That you are not retrieving unnecessary data, or in other words, retrieve only what you need.
2. If you indeed need all that data, then

   - Either increase the `memory_limit` value under your `php.ini` file
     **Con:** If your data keeps growing, you may need to keep updating this value for the only one script and exposing your self to memory leaks or running out of memory.
   - Or I would recommend that you implement some sort of pagination (which will allow you to keep memory limits in check) and make your application more scalable.

Answer (score 0):

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

Comment: By -1, it will unlimit memory and can be leaked. You should avoid this configuration, use it when you have no choice.