# Second laravel project(v5.4) PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, serve

this is my second laravel project running on the same machine. the first works just fine.

I use xampp for the projects.

after I install another fresh new version(5.4) laravel, when I run

> artisan serve

phpstorm tell me

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in E:\xampp\htdocs*****\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 549
>
> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 262144 bytes) in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs*****\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php
>   on line 549
>
> Process finished with exit code 255 at 13:58:28.
>   Execution time: 4,976 ms.

I tried [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555194/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate) about this, and tried to change php.ini. It does not apply to my case.

Comment: Does running it in the web browser produce the same error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't sound like a server setup issue. This is a Laravel setup issue. Increasing memory_limit in the php.ini will not fix the issue in your case. Laravel will commonly throw unhelpful errors if not setup correctly.

After running composer, make sure before you try to run `php artisan serve` that you have done the following.

1. Root is pointed to `/public` folder
2. Run composer install. You may be missing some vendor folders
3. Permissions of `/storage` are `777`. `/storage/logs/laravel.log` <- here you will find your real error.
4. Make sure to create `.env` aka a copy of `.env.example`
5. Generate a key `php artisan key:generate`

Also be careful that you don't have any spaces when creating your variables in your `.env` file this will cause problems as well.

- bad `DB_DATABASE=my database name`
- good `DB_DATABASE=my_database_name`

Lastly if you are running something like MAMP you may have to include a `UNIX_SOCKET` variable in your .env file like so:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=your_database_name_here
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
UNIX_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

and create the variable in your /config/database.php file

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    ...
    'engine' => null,
    'unix_socket'   => env('UNIX_SOCKET','')
],
```

Comment: Thanks @user3029357 . you get the right direction for this. looks like there was something wrong with the hosting setting.

Comment: Currently people are down voting, please explain? I believe its because they think its a server setup question. This is a Laravel question. Increasing `memory_limit` in the php.ini will not fix this issue. This a common error thrown when Laravel isn't setup correctly.

Comment: Thanks  @BlueYama I tried to vote for but the system told me I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: I had the same issue on a brand new laravel project, just set up without any own code. It turned out that the permissions on /storage were the reason. Thank you for this helpful article!

Answer (score 0):

You must have some kind of bug in your code - e.g. circular reference or other error. Calling `php artisan serve` certainly should not use 130+ MB ram.

Fix the bug and try again... php artisan serve should use a max of say 20mb?

If you really want to run the code, then try `php -d memory_limit=500M artisan serve` which will increase the mem available to php for that particular process.

Comment: Thank you for the effort. but,like I said, I did try to increase the memory_limit in the php.ini file which is not working in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain a bit more of what your project is about?

I ask because that error is directly related to what a single PHP script is trying to load in memory, i.e.: loading a Model or a File, and the resulting object would use more than the memory allowed per script under the `php.ini` configuration.

Looking at the error, your `php.ini` is set to have a max script memory usage of 128Mb (134217728 bytes/1024 Kb /1024 Mb) and whatever is loading is trying to load an extra 256Kb.

I'd recommend two things

1. Check your `php.ini` to confirm your memory limits (`memory_limit = ?`)
2. Provide the full stack trace so we can help you diagnose (*I'm guessing the container is trying to load a model from DB, and the data size is quite large that when loaded, it goes over the limit stablished*)

Comment: The project is clean laravel I just downloaded from laravel server. Like I said, I tried to change the memory_limit in php.ini but it's not working.  Also, what I posted are all I got  for the full stack trace. yeah, there is nothing else.

Comment: While I think of other alternatives, I have another question. If you set the memory limit to 256Mb, after restarting Apache, does it throw the same error (same number of bytes)? (_If so, then the php.ini you are modifying is not the one read by the application_)(_which can be a side effect of how XAMPP is configured_)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check your Laravel configuration, and ensure that all the configuration files (inside the `config/` directory) are valid PHP.

I had this issue when my `config/app.php` file was missing a '`,`' between two array items.

Answer (score -1):

**in my case the issue was in AppServiceProvider => register method**

**i removed that and the project remain working**

**Note this is the same error but on Laravel 8 in my case **

```
if ($this->app->environment('local')) {
             $this->app->register(\Laravel\Telescope\TelescopeServiceProvider::class);
             $this->app->register(TelescopeServiceProvider::class);
         }
```