# How reduce memory in array_multisort function

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Before i use array_multisort, execute my query and use loop for output 
my problem evertime use array_multisort , it gives me this error.

**Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 549453824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 524288 bytes)**

***Update : in my php.ini memory_limit is 1024 and i do not want to do it anymore !***

```
$result = $query->execute();

while( $record = $result->fetchAssoc() ) { 
    $items[] = $record;
}

// Sort by Order_id
 array_multisort(array_column($items, 'nid'), SORT_DESC,
            array_column($items, 'order_id'),      SORT_ASC,
            $items);
```

**UPDATE 2 :**

After this i use this

```
    foreach ($items as $row) {

      $hash[$row['nid']] = $row;
      $name[$row['nid']][] = $row['name'];
      $hash[$row['nid']]['name'] = array_unique($name[$row['nid']]);

      $tagname[$row['nid']][] = $row['tagsdata_name'];
      $hash[$row['nid']]['tagsdata_name'] = array_unique($tagname[$row['nid']]);

      $file[$row['nid']][] = $row['filename'];
      $hash[$row['nid']]['filename'] = array_unique($file[$row['nid']]);
    }
    $resultfinal = ($hash);

    array_multisort(//array_column($resultfinal, 'producttitle_title'), SORT_DESC,
                    array_column($resultfinal, 'created'),      SORT_DESC,
                    array_column($resultfinal, 'changed'),      SORT_DESC,
                    $resultfinal);
```

Comment: What you are doing via PHP, I am sure you could do that by an SQL query. Can you gives us more context of what query was executed and what is the purpose of the query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555194/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate ?

Comment: How many records do you have in `$result`? if you use simple sort function do you also gets this error?

Comment: my out items should be 20 item per page @DavidWinder

Comment: @vivek_23 not duplicate dude..my memory limit is 1024 !

Comment: Did you try to run this as stand-alone code in other machines?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 87 bytes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555194/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate)

Comment: @DavidWinder yes code is right but when my out is lot memory gives a error !

Comment: Does simple sort function also fails or only `array_multisort`?

Comment: @DavidWinder Just array_multisort gives error

Comment: Then I would suggest to use `array_multisort` on narrowed array and then use the keys. I guess you have `$record["id"]`?

Comment: Mr @DavidWinder Update my Problem . see

Comment: I'm little bit confuse - does the error come at the first or the second `array_multisort`? And what is the propose of the `foreach`? you add data to each row and then calling `array_multisort` again?