# fatal error for PHPExcel for large amount of data

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP application running out of Memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847396/php-application-running-out-of-memory)
>   [Allowed memory size of X bytes exhausted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096582/allowed-memory-size-of-x-bytes-exhausted)

> Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 94 bytes) in /home/extremew/public_html/florista/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/Worksheet.php on line 942

Comment: Do you know that there is a powerfull search engine on Stackoverflow? You [**should use it**](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+Allowed+memory+size) !

Comment: Have you tried using any of PHPExcel's memory saving features, such as cell caching?

Comment: Please check this link and all links inside [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560053/phpexcel-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted)

Comment: "PHPExcel's memory saving features, such as cell" will you please explain this in briff

Comment: Cell Caching is described in section 4.2.1 of the developer documentation... it basically provides aseries of options to reduce the memory needed to hold cell data in memory

Answer (score 2):

PHP is running out of memory, you can fix this by increasing your PHP memory limit in php.ini

Try this:

`memory_limit 64M`

Then restart apache.

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase your php memory. There are 3 ways to do it.

Often provider don't give permissions to php.ini or disabled the function in .htacces to increase memory. Than you only have the chance to do it directly in php.

---

### php.ini

Change this line `memory_limit = 64M` After that you must restart your webserver.

### direct php

Use `ini_set('memory_limit', '64M');` to set are memory size.

### .htaccess

Add `php_value memory_limit 64M` to your file.

---

**EDIT :** Change value in examples.

**EDIT 2 :** There are a lot of people which have the same question. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560053/phpexcel-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted)!

Comment: Thank you sir, but problem still remains......... Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 105 bytes) in /home/extremew/public_html/florista/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/Worksheet.php on line 942

Comment: You should change the value of memory. The 16M is only an example.

Comment: I have tried 16M, 32M, 64M 128M but no change in o/p